# Jenkins ver. 2.32.3 - can't install selenium plugin

Tags: php, selenium, jenkins, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I try to use jenkins to test my PHP facebook webdriver selenium project.
Jenkins fails to install the selenium plugin. It just loads forever on the installation process:

[image: jenkins fails]

In the plugin description I found out that I have to run jenkins on Java 8.

> (!) This plugin requires Jenkins to run under Java 8 as of version
>   3.1.0 (!)

So I have installed the latest version from the repository...

```
java version "1.8.0_121"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_121-b13)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.121-b13, mixed mode)
```

...and tried it again. But still the installation process does not make any progress. It stays for hours.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Go to `C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\jenkins.err.log` or wherever your Jenkins is installed, clear the file, restart the Jenkins instance, try downloading again, and open up that file and see if there are any relevant error messages there

Comment: It is installed now, the install process just took many many hours and I just had to wait.